# Why does "basename <(readlink -f filename)" return "63", not the actual basename?

Tags: bash

Is it possible to use `basename` and `readlink` in a one line? Something like:

```
ln -s /usr/local/src symlink
echo `basename <(readlink -f "./symlink")`
```

except that script above prints `63` instead of `src`.

Comment: I've tried to make the title specific to the actual question being asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) instead of the [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution):

```
echo "$(basename "$(readlink -f "./symlink")")"
```

or, if that's your complete line, `echo` is redundant:

```
basename "$(readlink -f "./symlink")"
```

Multiple `$(..)` command substitutions *can be nested* without any escaping or quoting needed (unlike with the old-style backquote version). Also note that if the substitution appears within double quotes, word splitting and filename expansion are not performed on the results.

To clarify the difference: when you say `<(cmd)`, the `cmd` is executed and *the result* is made available *in a file*, handle to which is returned, something like `/dev/fd/63`. Since the `basename` acts on a filename given, not its contents, it returns `63`.

Unlike process substitution, the `$(cmd)` will execute the `cmd` and return the result of command (its standard output). You can then store it in a variable, like `res=$(cmd)`, or reuse it in-place, like `cmd "$(cmd)"`.